# Memory overflow connected with php debug bar

Tags: debug

I'm having a bizarre problem on a testing server. The environment is Debian 12 (pre release) with PHP 8.2.5. Joomla 4.3.1. With debug enabled, huge amounts of session data are generated. This is shown by running Payage test component, which makes ajax calls every six seconds. After about a minute 512 MB is exhausted.

A variety of error messages are possible, but all appear connected with session data and php debug bar.

The same software running on an apparently identical server (Debian 12, PHP 8.2.5) runs happily with 128 MB.

How might I resolve this? Is there any documentation for php debug bar in Joomla? Can it be turned off without losing all the debug functionality?

Is the fact that PHPDEBUGBAR_STACK_DATA never shows anything connected?